# Writing complex trigger using JDBC, How to properly escape

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, triggers

This is a trigger I wrote in MySql WorkBench to save newly created row as json.

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER insert_movies AFTER INSERT ON movies
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
  SET @json = " { ";
  SET @json = CONCAT(@json,"\"","tableName","\"",":","\"","movies","\"",",");
  SET @json = CONCAT(@json,"\"","action","\"",":","\"","insert","\"",",");
  SET @json = CONCAT(@json,"\"","NewData","\"",":");
  SET @json = CONCAT(@json," { ");
  IF NEW.id is not null then
  SET @json = CONCAT(@json, "\"","ID","\"", ":", "\"",replace(NEW.id,'"','\\"'), "\"");
  END IF;
  if New.title is not null then 
  SET @json = CONCAT(@json, ",");
  SET @json = CONCAT(@json, "\"","TITLE","\"", ":", "\"",replace( NEW.title,'"','\\"'), "\"");
  END IF;
  SET @json = CONCAT(@json," } ");
  SET @json = CONCAT(@json, "}");
  INSERT INTO updated(d) values(@json);
END;
```

It worked. But I want to use JDBC to write this.

```
 Connection con = ds.getConnection();
 Statement sm = con.createStatement();
 StringBuilder triBuilder = new StringBuilder();
 triBuilder.append("CREATE TRIGGER insert_movies");
 ....
 triBuilder.append(" CONCAT(@json,\"\\\"\","tableName",\"\\\"\",\":\",\"\\\"\","movies","\"",",") ");
```

I tried but the escaping things become too complex and I can't get it to work. Help me please.

Comment: Use single quote ' on trigger instead of double quotes ", and your JDBC code will be more easy to escape.

Comment: @IvanCachicatari write me an example please.